# company-mode on Windows partially completes

Tags: company-mode, c++

I installed LLVM on my Windows machine. And now I want Emacs tools to use it. I changed company-clang-executable to "path/to/LLVM/bin/clang.exe". Now I think it finds Clang but somehow completions does not work. It only completes trivial things like main, double etc. I feel like I have to add some directories for company to look but I don't know how. I found ways of adding your own projet's directory but thats all.

EDIT: Here is what I did so far. I have;

```
(eval-after-load "company"
      (setq company-clang-arguments "-I/c/msys64/include"))
```

I also ofcourse did standard things from manual beforehand to enable company-clang. I also checked with Emacs M-! that Emacs recognize executable named clang. But still no completion.

Comment: Have you looked in the *clang-errors* buffer? It might complain about missing includes for example. I'm also struggling with company-clang on windows so I'm interested how this can be resolved.

Comment: I could not achieve it at the time and I still can't. Things work fine on Linux but not on Windows for reasons beyond me.

Comment: I'm at a point where (I think) clang finds all the headers and is now complaining about the actual code, which it apparently can't parse. Maybe some defines are missing...